# ERROR: gcloud.run.deploy Revision is not ready and cannot serve traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, node.js, gcloud, google-cloud-sql, gcp

I am new with GoogleCloud & GoogleCloudRun, I have deployed two applications at my Google active Project -

1. Next.JS app running at 3000 port
2. Express.js app running at 8080 port

When I tried to deploy another Express.JS application, I am getting port issue -

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision '...-00034-q4m' is
> not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed
> to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080
> environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more
> information.

### Please help me to resolve this issue.

Regards,
VBReddy

Comment: Start by including a minimal reproducible example. I have no idea what you wrote, how it is configured or how you deployed it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Although @JohnHanley is definitely right and we need a minimal reproducible example, a good place to start troubleshooting is always the logs https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging check if there is anything there that can help you figure it out and if you are still having problems please share the minimal reproducible example so we may help